# Delete a Column from an Old Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, sharepoint-workflow

I have a column that was created for a workflow that has since been deleted. I had created a workflow (2 years ago), and updated it multiple times. I was looking at the metadata of that list and noticed that a column named WorkflowName(Previous Version:12/23/2009 9:50:27 AM) still existed in my table. That workflow version had been deleted, and all reference to it (views) have been removed. But for some reason, it won't delete itself from the metadata. Further, i can't edit the list in Access because the workflow name is over 64 characters.

Any way i can manually delete this field/column from my metadata ( i actually have two different instances of this.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void DeleteWFField(string ListName,  SPWeb s)
    {

        s.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        string preName = "_x062b__x0628__x062a__x0648__x0634__x0645__x0627__x0631_";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                SPField f = s.Lists[ListName].Fields.GetField(preName + i.ToString());
                f.ReadOnlyField = false;
                f.Update(true);
                s.Lists[ListName].Update();
                f.Delete();
            }
            catch { }
        }
        s.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```